# UIImageOrientationRight(left) won't work

Tags: iphone

I want to pick a photo from UIImagePickerController and check the photo if it is landscape. if selected photo is landscape, I want to rotate to portrait.
so, here is my code

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

    if(image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight || image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft){

        UIImage *retatedImg = [image imageRotatedByDegrees:90];

    }else {
        UIImage *retatedImg = image;

    }
}
```

I'm sure [imageRotatedByDegrees:] method is working fine. Just stuck why it does not recognize landscape photo. help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imageOrientation property doesn't refer to the format of the image. When you load an image, the value for that property depends of the EXIF data in the file, if any. If the camera that take the photo saves it with the final format, it will not include EXIF data for image orientation changes.

If you want to know if that image format is portrait or landscape, compare the width and height dimensions instead of using imageOrientation.

```
if( image.size.width > image.size.height ) 
    UIImage *retatedImg = [image imageRotatedByDegrees:90] ;
```